# Show label "Low in stock" for configurable products

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

Hello guys the version that i`m using is Magento 1.7.0.2,

I want to create a label for the configurable products, that will appear when the total quantity will be under 5. The label will be "Low in stock" and will appear on the category page on the image just like in this example.

Right now i am using extension EM Product Labels, but this works only on simple products, because the simple product has just 1 type of quantity in stock.

You can find example on this link :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fELmf.png

Basicaly i need : WHEN QTY OF CONFIGURABLE PRODUCT IS LOWER THEN 5 DISPLAY LABEL :)

Comment: Have you lowered the stock level of all the products associated to the configurable product to 5. Just Curious? The out of stock will show on Configurable when all the associated products are out of stock. May be the same on this mod.

Comment: I did everything regarding the stock for configurable products, but the "low in stock" label did not showed. The label out of stock appears if the configurable products are 0 in stock.